# How do I interpret NaN values in statsmodels.stats.anova_lm result

Tags: anova, statsmodels

I am trying to compare two models using `statsmodels.stats.anova_lm`. The output table I get is:

```
   df_resid         ssr  df_diff   ss_diff         F  Pr(>F)
0      72.0  113.319956      0.0       NaN       NaN     NaN
1      74.0  115.497953     -2.0 -2.177997  0.697726     NaN
```

I appreciate that there will always be `NaN`s in the 0th row. But I don't understand the `NaN` in the later row. Is it because it ran out of floats resolution?

Comment: `NaN` is an absorbing operand for mathematical operations. For example, a float plus a `Nan` is a `Nan`. So first ensure that your original data is `Nan`-free. The second issue that can come up which might produce a `Nan` is when an undefined operation, such as division by zero, is computed. Another example is taking the logarithm of zero.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The data is 100% NaN free. All the coefficients in the model are non NaN. The model formula is a sum of products. Also, if there were any NaNs in the data set, I'd expect my F statistic to be NaN too.

Comment: @Noah apparently switching the order helps! I think it deserves an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @ivaigult glad it helped. I made my comment an answer since it seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: @ivaigult Yes, please bring this to the developers' attention.

Comment: The issue seem to have been reported long ago, but it's closed now: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be an error in how `statsmodels` produces p-values. Usually with an F-test, you need to supply the degrees of freedom for the test, and these degrees of freedom must be positive. `statsmodels` should automatically take the absolute value of the degrees of freedom and sums of squares, but maybe it didn't. Try switching the order of the models, which should produce the same values but make the degrees of freedom positive.